# Unable to export animated model in MD5 format

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am trying to export this animated model(It has 6 planes which fold to become a cube). I am getting the error on "Plane.004" saying `The 'Plane.004' object contains 4 vertices with no deformation weights assigned` I have even attached the screenshot of the blender editor with the error. I am using `io_scene_md5` script to export the model in **MD5**

[image]

You can see the hierarchy as well in the editor. Please help me to export this animation in MD5 format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for duplicate verts or verts that unattached to any edge? I'm sure this exporter works. I made some ETQW models with it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAHLSPG2v_s